# cv2.VideoCapture error when open Gstreamer pipeline

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, video-capture

I'm trying to open gstreamer pipeline with opencv-python on window10 like this

```
cv2.VideoCapture('videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,framerate=20/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

I have installed gstreamer and test it, but VideoCapture is not open.
So I used `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` and checked gstreamer is not built like below

```
Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.91.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.45.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.51.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.7.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      NO
```

And now, I don't know how to build opencv with gstreamer.:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this exact same frustrating problem. Fortunately, there's a handy guide to resolving it here: https://medium.com/@galaktyk01/how-to-build-opencv-with-gstreamer-b11668fa09c

In summary, you have to manually build gstreamer opencv with cmake in order to properly configure it. It takes about 1-2 hours in my experience, with 1hr compile time. Hope it works for you!